# How can I unhide .git file by default?

Tags: windows, git

When I use `.git init` .git file is always hidden by default, I have to always  unselect the hidden option in properties. What is the way I can change this default setting?

Also when I `del .git` only the config,description and HEAD file are deleted,not the entire .git folder. How can I change this default setting so I don't have to always unhide after `git init` ?

I'm using windows 8.1

Comment: My (little bit oriented...) 2 cent: use the git bash command line (I suppose you are using [git for windows](https://gitforwindows.org/)) and you'll never ever bother with this again: `ls -a` to list all files/folders including hidden, `rm -rf .git` to remove the local repo and references.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think it is in your best interest that it stays hidden.

But in case you still want it to be visible.

I recommend you enable `show hidden files` folder view option on your windows.

[image]

This way the hidden `.git` folder will always be visible whenever you `git init`

Comment: That is what I have to do everytime ..but the purpose of asking this question was to know if there is any other way around. I mean not having to select "show hidden folders"

Comment: From my findings, this is the only option we have. On my system, I keep the option on all the time. Have a great time @AjiteshRanjan

Answer (score 2):

[core.hideDotFiles](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corehideDotFiles)

> (Windows-only) If true, mark newly-created directories and files whose name starts with a dot as hidden. If dotGitOnly, only the .git/ directory is hidden, but no other files starting with a dot. The default mode is dotGitOnly.

```
> git config --global core.hideDotFiles false
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess you should just be able to type "show hidden files and folders" into your search bar on Windows and turn on show all file extensions, and hidden files. That should work then. Or run `ls -a` to view all files in that directory too.